# Interleaved stereo linear interpolation

Tags: audio, linear-interpolation

I am implementing real time linear interpolation of audio data, which is stored in interleaved audio buffers. Audio files can be single- or multichannel. In case of single channel audio files, I interpolate as follows:

```
f_dex = offset + ((position / oldlength) * (newlength * b_channelcount));
i_dex = trunc(f_dex); // get truncated index
fraction = f_dex - i_dex; // calculate fraction value for interpolation
b_read = (b_sample[i_dex] + fraction * (b_sample[i_dex + b_channelcount] - b_sample[i_dex]));
outsample_left += b_read;
outsample_right += b_read;
```

This sounds wonderful and I'm not having any issues. However, when I want to read multichannel files, I must correct the calculated read position to make sure it is on the first sample in the corresponding frame, such as:

```
f_dex = offset + ((position / oldlength) * (newlength * b_channelcount));
if ((long)trunc(f_dex) % 2) {
    f_dex -= 1.0;
}
i_dex = trunc(f_dex); // get truncated index
fraction = f_dex - i_dex; // calculate fraction value for interpolation
outsample_left += (b_sample[i_dex] + fraction * (b_sample[i_dex + b_channelcount] - b_sample[i_dex])) * w_read;
outsample_right += (b_sample[i_dex + 1] + fraction * (b_sample[(i_dex + 1) + b_channelcount] - b_sample[i_dex + 1])) * w_read;
```

Now this introduces some digital noise and I can't really explain why. Is there any other/better way to apply real time linear interpolation to interleaved stereo files?

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little confused by your variable names, `position`, `oldlength` and `outsample_left/outsample_right` seem to be for the output while `newlength` and `offset` are from the input, `b_sample`?

I think that your problem is including `b_channelcount` in the computation of `f_dex`. Try instead

```
f_dex = offset + ((position / oldlength) * newlength);
```

and you can leave out the `% 2` check and adjustment. That adjustment isn't doing what you intend.

Addendum 11/7:
I missed something, you also need to adjust your use of `i_dex`, as I've set up `f_dex` here it counts the whole block for each channel as 1. Where before you had `b_sample[i_dex]`, instead use `b_sample[i_dex*b_channelcount]`; this will put you on the first sample of the block (left if stereo). Likewise you can use `b_sample[i_dex*b_channelcount + 1]` for a right channel if there is one, `b_sample[(i_dex+1)*b_channelcount]` for the first sample of the next block for interpolation, etc.

Comment: `for (i = 0; i < newlength; i++) {
 f_dex = (i / oldlength) * newlength;
 i_dex = trunc(f_dex); // get truncated index
 fraction = f_dex - i_dex;
 b_read = buffer[i_dex] + fraction * (buffer[i_dex + b_channelcount] - buffer[i_dex]);
 out_left[i] = b_read * pan_left;
 out_right[i] = b_read * pan_right;
}`

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't seem to figure out how to post proper code in comments..if possible at all..Anyway this should make the variable names and intentions a bit clearer.  I see this working with single channel files, but it won't work with multi channel.  In addition, how can I make sure that the calculation for `f_dex` is on the first sample in the frame?

Comment: @MatthiasMüller a simple solution is to edit that code into the initial question (not necessarily replacing your old code though that is an option). I've edited my answer t cover the issue that `f_dex` (and thus `i_dex`) is now counting frames instead of individual samples.

Comment: Thank you very much @hcs! This solved my problem and the code runs stable now! And thanks for the tips concerning editing the posts.